# Android, Firestore: GlideException: Failed to load resource

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-storage, android-glide

I am trying to load an Image from my `firebase storage` and show it in my Cardview, but it doesn't work. The only thing I get is: `class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource` and `Oh, Something went wrong!` (my own Timber message). Here is my code

### XML

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="product"
            type="com.example.app.framework.datasource.models.product.Product" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
            android:id="@+id/mcv_product_item"
            android:layout_width="165dp"
            android:layout_height="210dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/iv_product_image"
                    android:layout_width="165dp"
                    android:layout_height="110dp"
                    android:contentDescription="TODO"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:loadImage="@{product.images[0]}" <-- Trying to load Image here
                    tools:src="@drawable/ic_calibrate" />

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_product_name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:maxLines="2"
                    android:text="@{product.name}"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/iv_product_image"
                    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/iv_product_image"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/iv_product_image"
                    tools:text="Test Name" />

                <com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_product_price"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                    android:text="@{product.price}"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/tv_product_name" />


            </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

### Data Class

```
data class Product(
    val name: String = "",
    val price: Float = 0F,
    val category: String = "",
    val note: String = "",
    val articelNumber: Int = 0,
    val images: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf(),
    val description: ArrayList<ProductDescription> = arrayListOf(),
    val technicalDescription: ArrayList<ProductDescription>? = arrayListOf(),
    val hasAccessories: Boolean = false
)

data class ProductDescription(
    val category: String = "",
    val body: String = "",
)
```

### Glide Binding Adapter

```
@BindingAdapter("loadImage")
fun setImageFromUrl(view: ImageView, url: String?) {
    if (!url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        GlideApp
            .with(view)
            .load(url)
            .fitCenter()
            .apply(RequestOptions.bitmapTransform(RoundedCorners(4)))
            .into(view)
    } else {
        Timber.d("Oh, Something went wrong!")
    }
}
```

### GlideAppModule

```
@GlideModule
class GlideAppModule : AppGlideModule() {
    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        super.registerComponents(context, glide, registry)
        registry.append(StorageReference::class.java, InputStream::class.java, FirebaseImageLoader.Factory())
    }
}
```

### Dependencies

```
implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.3.0"
implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0"
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.11.0"
kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.11.0"
```

### Stack trace (censored link)

```
com.example.app W/Glide: Load failed for gs://censored.appspot.com/products/images/censored-SET_an238386.png with size [433x289]
    class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
com.example.app D/BindingAdapterKt: Oh, Something went wrong!
```

I am getting my products objects from `cloud firestore` and everything in my cardview is loaded correctly except the corresponding images

I appreciate every help, thank you.

### EDIT

Adding a listener to `GlideApp` gives unfortunately no extra information,

```
@BindingAdapter("loadImage")
fun setImageFromUrl(view: ImageView, url: String?) {
    if (!url.isNullOrEmpty()) {
        GlideApp
            .with(view)
            .load(url)
            .addListener(
                object : RequestListener<Drawable> {
                    override fun onLoadFailed(
                        e: GlideException?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<Drawable>?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean,
                    ): Boolean {
                        if (e != null) {
                            Timber.d("Exception ist ${e.stackTraceToString()}")
                        }
                        return false
                    }

                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Drawable?,
                        model: Any?,
                        target: Target<Drawable>?,
                        dataSource: DataSource?,
                        isFirstResource: Boolean,
                    ): Boolean {
                        return false
                    }

                }
            )
            .into(view)
    } else {
        Timber.d("Oh, Something went wrong!")
    }
}
```

Error remains `class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource`. The permissions to load the image are also granted from `firebase cloud firestore`

Comment: Remove `fitCenter()` and try

Comment: @ADM No difference at all, still failing. To my mind it has something to do with the `size of the image view` and the `size of the image` itself

Comment: `ImageView` size should not be a problem. Try minimizing the problem first.  remove  `fitCenter()` and apply transformation and make sure u have internet on device. Add a listener to Glide image load method and debug the `Exception` .

Comment: @ADM Already removed `fitCenter()` and `.apply(/...)`, no difference at all. Adding a listener to Glide is absolutely useless as it tells me the same `GlideException: Failed to load resource`. Internet connection is available all the time, otherwise it would never get the `storage reference` and all other `product details` in the first place. I also `cleaned Build and Invalidated Caches`, nothing helped.

Answer (score 0):

### !! TEMPORARY SOLUTION !!

So I have found a temporary solution for my problem. Instead of saving:

```
gs://censored.appspot.com/products/images/censored-SET_an238386.png
```

as your reference to the image (which is the proper way, but here it does not work), extract the https by clicking

[image]

Then you will get something like (censored here):

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/censored.appspot.com
/o/products%2Fimages%2Fcensored-Leihgeraet_an326331.png?alt=media&token=censored-c92b-4153-a3f3-censored
```

Save this `https link` in your `cloud-firestore` database and then get it from there. The advantage over downloading the url link separately is, that the above method is much faster.

But as said, this should just be a temporary solution. I have opened an Issue at the Firebase-UI GitHub repository, and I am looking forward for a proper solution

Comment: Well i have used Firestore some times ago then i was saving only file name i.e `censored-SET_an238386.png` not the Url and it worked well with Glide. Have you tried with file name only ?

Comment: @ADM Well looks like that might be the solution. Only problem is, that I get `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /censored_an238386.png: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. My file is stored inside some folders, should I save the entire root?

Comment: Yeah give t a try

Comment: @ADM Nope, not working, do you know what the full path is? I am only getting `/product/images/myfolder/censored-SET_an238386.png` but I think something needs to be in front of `/product`

Answer (score 0):

It works with me in java

```
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:3.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
```

I'm using it inside Firestore RecyclerView adapter

```
    String imgPath = "images/"+membersModel.getUid();
    StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    StorageReference imageRef = storageRef.child(imgPath);
    imageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
            Glide.with(holder.VmemBpic.getContext())
                    .load(uri)
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_user)
                    .circleCrop()
                    .error(R.drawable.ic_user)
                    .into(holder.VmemBpic);
```